# How do I install courier-authdaemon on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

I am using a VPS from Contabo.com, and when using Digitalocean, I didn't have any problems.
Now, when trying to install courier-authdaemon, I get an error saying that the package could not be found. Does anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `courier-authdaemon` is available from `universe` repository, it can be enabled through:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install courier-authdaemon
```